# How to query multiple Child object of a parent in single soql query

Tags: soql, relationships, dynamic-soql

I have to bring the values of a multiple child object of a Parent object in single query,

I tried the following method , however for query one child object as a first step it throws me the following error:

Error: "Didn't understand relationship 'OrderTraining__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

the query is

```
newOrders = [select id,OrderNumber,(select Name__c from OrderTraining__r) from Order];
```

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: @SimonGovaert i tried that as well, the error is similar  "Didn't understand relationship 'OrderTraining' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

Comment: it mostly ends with orderTrainings__r. 's'  i feel. go to your child object open lookup/master field check 'Child Relationship Name' api name

Comment: Seems like I was wrong, syntax is correct indeed, as per doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is correct, check for the relation ship name `OrderTraining__r`.

Seems like OrderTraining is custom object, Navigate to lookup field on OrderTraining object to see the relationship name.

---

**added more details:**

[image]

- If relationship name is Resources, I would use Resources__r in my subquery.

Comment: The relationship name is OrderId__c , when I replaced it it throws me the same error. The lookup field will have the Order number

Comment: added an example

Comment: I got that it was my mistake I missed OrderTrainings  "s". Now I got it fixed. Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Put Child relationship name and add __r to it.
Example:

```
SELECT Id, (select Id from Taxi_Orders__r) FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Acme'
```